# Simulate an activity to postpone screen turn off

Tags: android

Each time an user touches screen, a timeout counter for turning screen off is reset.

How can I simulate an activity to reset such timeout counter programmatically, to postpone screen turning off?

**I am not looking for keeping screen on permanently.**

I am experiencing screen off issue when user is requested to use a fingerprint scanner and I want to reset such timeout counter each time when user's fingerprint is not recognized or any fingerprint sensor activity is recorded.

Comment: "How can I simulate an activity to reset such timeout counter programmatically, to postpone screen turning off? " -- AFAIK, you can't.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Do you think that `view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);` with `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` would be accepted by system as such event?

Comment: I think that just passes the event through your view hierarchy. I would be surprised if it has the desired impact.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is already there in the Android documentation.
It is called [Wake Lock.](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) Keep the screen on programmatically using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The advantage of setting the flag programmatically in your activity is that it gives you the option of programmatically clearing the flag later and thereby allowing the screen to **turn off**. If you want to explicitly clear the flag and thereby allow the screen to turn off again, use `clearFlags()` like so:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: That is not what I have asked in my question. Turning flag on and off doesn't simulate the activity. Turning the flag on and clear it after some time is not solution, since in the meantime there may be another real event and we don't know the system timeout value anyway. Question is how to simulate the activity same way as if you would touch the screen. So it is about resetting timeout counter. Am I clear enough?